# Flutter FutureBuilder returning null

Tags: flutter, dart

here i'm trying to return the `animedetailjson` inside `Future<void> getJsonanimedetail()` to `Container` so i can show the data on (maybe) a widget but the problem is, the `FutureBuilder` is returning `null` even though the `print` inside `Future<void> getJsonanimedetail()` is working. I've read some similiar topic about this problem, but i'm having difficult time understanding other's people code, i'm really new to programming, so i apologize for asking the same question(but with my own code )

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class detailscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  detailscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<detailscreen> createState() => _detailscreenState();
}

class _detailscreenState extends State<detailscreen> {
  _detailscreenState();
  @override
  Future<void> getJsonanimedetail() async {
    final animedetailresponse = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/5114/full'),   
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (animedetailresponse.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Anime Details FOUND');
    } else
      (print('Anime Details ERROR'));
    if (mounted) {
      setState(
        () {
          var animedetailjson = jsonDecode(animedetailresponse.body)['data'];
          print(animedetailjson['title']);
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getJsonanimedetail(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

btw this is for my first bootcamp project but unfortunately, i choose the wrong bootcamp, they're so unprofessional, a lot of question in the chat are not getting any reply, the trainer often skips to the next message even though the question is clearly right above the message he's replying, he even fell asleep even though previously he said that he'll start an online livesession

Comment: ` future: getJsonanimedetail(),` is broken. Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @RandalSchwartz thank u very much, The video is really helpful since it shows something like "doing A will results in B", i can understand it more easily,  especially for the the looping/number restart part because previously i thought the code will only run once and not rerunning the build method. Tbh it's kinda difficult for me to understand the documentation, when i read english which is not my native language, i tend to forget what the previous sentece said, my brain is only focusing on translating the words so that's my i prefer learning from real use case directly like ur video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the FutureBuilder structure, you can check comment links. Your current future method return nothing(void), that's why you are getting null

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class detailscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  detailscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<detailscreen> createState() => _detailscreenState();
}

class _detailscreenState extends State<detailscreen> {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getJsonanimedetail() async {
    final animedetailresponse = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/5114/full'),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (animedetailresponse.statusCode == 200) {
      log('Anime Details FOUND');
      var animedetail =
          jsonDecode(animedetailresponse.body)['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return animedetail; // better return list
    } else {
      log('Anime Details ERROR');
    }
  }

  late final future = getJsonanimedetail();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("empty Data");
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.data?["title"]}"));
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("got Error");
            }

            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: thank u so much for giving the working version of the code, as for the documentation i apologize since i'ts kinda hard for me to understand it due to my poor brain and english skill limitation but thankfully Randal commented out his video link in the previous comment. I'll try to compare ur code with mine, hopefully i can get some clue from it 